# Exception thrown when building EAR after switching to JDK 7

Tags: netbeans, ejb, java-7

i'm trying to port my application to JDK 7 from JDK 6 and its giving this exception when i'm trying to build the project in Netbeans IDE.

```
Error starting Sun's native2ascii: 
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.native2ascii.SunNative2Ascii.run(SunNative2Ascii.java:67)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.native2ascii.DefaultNative2Ascii.convert(DefaultNative2Ascii.java:54)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.Native2Ascii.convert(Native2Ascii.java:268)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.Native2Ascii.execute(Native2Ascii.java:227)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.native2ascii.Native2AsciiMojo.executeAnt(Native2AsciiMojo.java:115)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.native2ascii.Native2AsciiMojo.execute(Native2AsciiMojo.java:92)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.tools.native2ascii.Main
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClassDirect(RealmClassLoader.java:195)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassRealm.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassRealm.java:274)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClass(RealmClassLoader.java:214)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:188)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.native2ascii.SunNative2Ascii.run(SunNative2Ascii.java:51)
```

please help me on fixing this. Thanks in advance.

regards.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing this without changing the libs related to complication is by upgrading ative2ascii-maven-plugin to higher version (at least 1.0-beta-1). In addition to that, please make sure that the following configurations are correctly in place.

1. All includes should be enclosed with .
2. Similarly all excludes should be enclosed with

Eg:

```
      
     .....
    <includes>
    <include>
      ApplicationResources_.properties,
      ApplicationResources_.properties
    </include> 
    </includes>
```

Comment: Beware though, the beta-1 version does not behave exactly the same as the alpha-1. Excluded resources used to be copied and processed by the alpha-1 version, while the beta-1 version silently ignores them... See : http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MOJO-1833

Answer (score 1):

Hi after some R & D i was a able to fix this issue by adding the following plugin in maven pom file.

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>native2ascii-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <dependencies>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
             <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
             <version>1.7.0</version>
             <scope>system</scope>
             <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
 </plugin>
```